# React Django REST framework session is not persisting/working

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm working on a project with Django Rest Framework as back-end and React as front-end. When I set a session variable initially in some function/view and later when I try to access the different view through axios call and in that view if I try to access session variable which i created previously, I get KeyError. Session doesn't seem stored.

I googled I got a similar issue which I'm facing.

[Django rest framework Reactjs sessions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638749/django-rest-framework-reactjs-sessions-not-working)

I followed the process by adding **{ withCredentials: true }** in axios call. Now I'm getting a different error. Now the issue is not able to access the backend. I get an error saying **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/url/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy**

Again I googled the issue which I'm getting and found that I've to add CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST in the django settings.py

I followed the below post for that

[Django Python rest framework, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in chrome, works in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357687/django-python-rest-framework-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

I have added CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST like this

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
]
```

Still, I'm facing the same issue. I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally after so much of research I found a solution for this.

In the file where we are importing axios to make the call, set the default header below your import
**axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;**

example:

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.get("url")
.then(response => { 
   console.log(response) 
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

once this is done go to your settings.py file and add the below configuration

**CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True**

**CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True**

so after this if you set a session variable and access it later in any view, you would be able to get the value which you had previously stored.

This solution worked for me. Hopefully if anyone has the same issue, it will work for them too. :)

**NOTE**

If the session is not storing under **localhost:3000** then make sure that you're accessing your front-end application through **127.0.0.1:3000**. If you access the front-end application through **localhost** and if your backend is running on **127.0.0.1** then the session cookie will be set to **127.0.0.1**, so changing the front-end URL from **localhost:3000** to **127.0.0.1:3000** will solve your problem.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this solution worked!

Comment: In addition, I was using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, and I updated that to match the  `127.0.0.1` domain, and that made it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once. I used firefox as a browser and got the problem solved by installing the CORS everywhere plugin for firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/). So, if you're using firefox, this might solve your problem.