# Session variable in one route exists, and in other is None

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Currently I'm working on a project where I'm using React as frontend and Django as backend. In react i created a login page, where I through axios send files to django, and in this route index i sent all the information from the login page, and define a session variable `reqeuset.session['id']=150` in it. But when i call `reqeust.session['id']` in a diffrent route, it says that it is type `None`.

This is the code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def index(request):
     data=request.data.get('data')
     korisnik = Korisnik.objects.filter(korisnicko_ime=data.get('user'),
     if korisnik.exists():
         korisnik_json=serializers.serialize('json',korisnik)
         request.session['id']=150
         print(request.session['id'])
        # if not request.session.session_key:
        #    request.session.create()
         return HttpResponse(korisnik_json)
     else: return HttpResponse(status=404)

 @api_view(['GET']) 
 def korisnik(request,id):
     print(request.session.get('id'))
     korisnik=Korisnik.objects.filter(pk=id)
     korisnik_json=serializers.serialize('json',korisnik)
     return HttpResponse(korisnik_json)
```

This is the output from python console
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Zsw.png)

Also note, I'm using django restframework. Did anyone, have this problem before, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the session is not persisting between the route changes. Can you share your Axios code? are you using withCredentials in you axios code?

Comment: Here is the axios code https://pastebin.com/F5sTskDg, i don't use withCredentials i tried putting withCredentials=true, but then i get this error https://imgur.com/chDH9qr

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept it as the answer here and in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced a similar issue. Please check my answer here.

[React Django REST framework session is not persisting/working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305141/react-django-rest-framework-session-is-not-persisting-working)

Comment: Yes, this is the answer it works know, here is the proof https://imgur.com/ipCpOs1 Thank you very much