# Cookie not set in Request Headers with cors site in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
axios.post('http://drupal-site.local/user/login?_format=json',{
    "name": username,
    "pass": password
  }).then(resp..................})
```

Here I'm calling Drupal login API in react(http://localhost:3000). Cookies are not set in headers. If I'm calling in postman same API then cookies are setting in headers.
I tried with `{withCredentials: true}` and include: credentials but no use.

```
 axios.post('http://drupal-site.local/user/login?_format=json', {
  "name": username,
  "pass": password
}, {
  withCredentials: true, // or 
  credentials: include
})
.then(() => {})
```

Comment: Axios makes an asynchronous request, while postman is a browser (chrome extension)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I already tried with {withcredentials:true} and credentials: include also but no use