# Cross-Domain Session Cookie (Express API on Heroku + React App on Netlify)

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, session-cookies, express-session

I have a React App making calls to an API in node.js/Express.

Frontend is deployed in Netlify (https), Backend deployed on Heroku (https).

My problem:

- Everything working in dev environment (localhost)
- In production (Netlify/Heroku), the api calls to register and login seem to work but the **session cookie is not stored in the browser**. Because of that, any other calls to protected routes in the API fail (because I don't receive the user credentials).

[image: cross-domain authentication cookie react express]

*Talking is cheap, show me the code....*

#### Backend (Express API):

- I'm using [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) (local strategy), [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

**App.js**

```js
require('./configs/passport');

// ...

const app = express();

// trust proxy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958647/express-not-sending-cross-domain-cookies)
app.set("trust proxy", 1); 

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'lax',
      maxAge: 60000000,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    ttl: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// ...


app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_APP_URL]
  })
);

//...

app.use('/api', require('./routes/auth-routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/item-routes'));
```

**CRUD endpoint (ex. item-routes.js):**

```js
// Create new item
router.post("/items", (req, res, next) => {
    Item.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        owner: req.user._id // <-- AT THIS POINT, req.user is UNDEFINED
    })
    .then(
        // ...
    );
});
```

#### Frontend (React App):

- Using Axios with the option "withCredentials" set to true...

**User registration and login:**

```js
class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    let service = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      withCredentials: true
    });
    this.service = service;
  }
  
  signup = (username, password) => {
    return this.service.post('/signup', {username, password})
    .then(response => response.data)
  }

  login = (username, password) => {
    return this.service.post('/login', {username, password})
    .then(response => response.data)
  }
   
  //...
}
```

**Creating a new item...:**

```
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/items`, {
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description,
    }, {withCredentials:true})
    .then( (res) => {
        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Short answer:

It wasn't working as expected because I was testing on Chrome Incognito and, by default, **Chrome blocks third party cookies in Incognito mode** ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63288107/11298742)).

Below is a list with some things to check if you're having a similar issue ;)

---

### Checklist

In case it helps, here's a checklist with different things that you main need ;)

- **(Backend) Add "trust proxy" option**

If you're deploying on Heroku, add the following line (you can add it before your session settings).

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

- **(Backend) Check your session settings**

In particular, check the option `sameSite` and `secure` ([more details here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/)).

The code below will set `sameSite: 'none'` and `secure: true` in production:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'Super Secret (change it)',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'lax', // must be 'none' to enable cross-site delivery
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // must be true if sameSite='none'
    }
  })
);
```

- **(Backend) CORS config**

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_APP_URL]
  })
);
```

- **(Backend) Environment Variables**

Setup the environment variables in Heroku. For example:

```
FRONTEND_APP_URL = https://my-project.netlify.app
```

**IMPORTANT**: For the CORS URL, avoid a trailing slash at the end. The following may not work:

```
FRONTEND_APP_URL = https://my-project.netlify.app/ --> avoid this trailing slash!
```

- **(Frontend) Send credentials**

Make sure you're sending credentials in your API calls (you need to do that for all calls you make to the API, including the call for user login).

If you're using axios, you can do use `withCredentials` option. For example:

```
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_API_URL}/items`, {
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description,
    }, {withCredentials:true})
    .then( (res) => {
        // ...
    });
```

- **(Browser) Check the configuration for third-party cookies**

For testing, you probably want to make sure you're using the default configuration provided by each browser.

For example, as of 2021, Chrome blocks third-party cookies in Incognito mode (but not in "normal" mode), so you probably want to have something like this:

[image]

- **...and deal with browser restrictions...:**

Finally, keep in mind that each browser has a different policy for third party cookies and, in general, those restrictions are expected to increase in the coming years.

For example, Chrome is expected to block third-party cookies at some point in 2023 ([source](https://www.theverge.com/2021/6/24/22547339/google-chrome-cookiepocalypse-delayed-2023)).

If your App needs to bypass those restrictions, here are some options:

- Implement Backend & Frontend under the same domain
- Implement Backend & Frontend under subdomains of the same domain (example, example.com & api.example.com)
- Have your Backend API under a proxy (if you're using Netlify, you can easily [setup a proxy using a _redirects file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59314882/11298742))

Comment: Hey man, 
I tried your method for storing httpOnly cookie to maintain a session but browser isn't storing cookies in application but i do get them in response
i.e when i login i create a token and save it in request its an httpONly true token with sameSIte none and secure also i have added trust proxy before cors and cookie parser
still not working

Comment: @MohammadFahad check the last 2 points ("Check the configuration for third-party cookies" & "...and deal with browser restrictions..."). If that doesn't solve your problem best option is to post a different question and provide code so that others can help you ;)

Comment: you're a legend dude, i spent 2 whole days looking for solutions , the samesite: "none" fixed it for me

Comment: Have answered in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071547/cookies-not-sent-with-cross-origin-request/72663708#72663708

Comment: This works for me but weirdly only on desktop...

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes down to third party cookies.

If you're sending data from *server.herokuapp.com* to *site.herokuapp.com* you're going to have this issue.

**The solution is to use a custom domain for your Heroku applications.**

Please see this post for more details: [Cookies Only set in Chrome - not set in Safari, Mobile Chrome, or Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384430/cookies-only-set-in-chrome-not-set-in-safari-mobile-chrome-or-mobile-safari)