# Cookies not sent with cross-origin-request

Tags: axios, fetch, cross-domain, react-cookie

After days of searching and trying, I'm here now.

I deployed the React Application in **Netlify** and the Node.js backend in **Heroku**. Everything works fine in localhost environment. But after deploying, cookies are not sent in request header.

CORS:(Backend Node.js)

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: CORS_ORIGIN,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Accept,User-Agent,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,cache-control"
}));
```

Axios:

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export default axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + "/api",
   headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND,
   },
});
```

Fetching Data(Mutation): apiClient is imported from above Axios.js and cookies is handled by react-cookies

```
apiClient.post("/auth/login",{ email: "name@mail.com", password: "pawspaws" })
    .then((res) => {
            setCookie("jwt", res.data.accessToken, { path: process.env.REACT_APP_PATH || "/", domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN, maxAge: 26000, secure: true, sameSite: 'None' });
            setCookie("refresh", res.data.refreshToken, { path: process.env.REACT_APP_PATH || "/", domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN, maxAge: 2600000, secure: true, sameSite: 'None' });
            setCookie("user", res.data.user, { path: process.env.REACT_APP_PATH || "/", domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN, maxAge: 26000, secure: true, sameSite: 'None' });
         }).catch((err) => console.log(err.response))
```

Above code sets the cookies.. and it's working.

Now, below is the request I'm sending which doesn't send the Cookies along with the request:

```
apiClient.get("/posts/timeline", { params: { email: "name@mail.com" } })
         .then((res) => { console.log(res.data); })
         .catch((err) => { console.log(err.response) });
```

[image: Cookies in FireFox]
[image]
Well, it returns **unauthorized** since the Cookie is not sent at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found my own solution.. It was pretty easy.. It was setting up **proxy**

Just added line below to package.json in frontend:

```
"proxy":"https://random.name.herokuapp.com",
```

FYI, for *Netlify*, we need additional _redirects file in public folder.

_redirects

```
/api/* https://random.name.herokuapp.com/api/:splat 200
/*     /index.html                                  200
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had hardcoded my front end api calls to the herokubackend

`axios.get("https://infinite-ocean-8435679.herokuapp.com/api/user")`

First removed the hrokupart from the request like this

`axios.get("/api/loguserin")`

Then added the proxy value to the bottom of the package.json

`"proxy":"https://infinite-ocean-8435679.herokuapp.com",`

Next added a file called _redirects inside the react public folder.(_redirects is the file name and it has no extension such as .txt so don't add _redirects.txt )

Add the following inside _redirects file

```
/api/* https://infinite-ocean-8435679.herokuapp.com/api/:splat 200
/*     /index.html                                  200
```

inside _redirects file formatting will be weird just add above code replacing heroku part with your backend url.
React automatically add all the files inside the public folder to its build folder once created.

deploy the site to Netlify

Comment: I did everything as you said but the redirects is somehow not working as the request URL is not changing to the heroku backend but stays like the frontend URL `https://randomapp.netlify.app/api/users/sign-in`