# Django session authentication and Axios POST signals

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I use Django Rest framework session authentication,after user logged in I can do successful POST request (/api/post/1/like/) using browsable API.

Why can't I post using axios ? (user instance is must for Django server to save the above API )

I hope POST signal may not know logged in user even though I am loggedin as admin user

AXIOS FUNCTION

```
const likebutton = (id)=>{
           axios.post(`/api/post/${id}/like/`)         
    }
```

ERROR

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Comment: Probably something to do with CSRF protection unless this is being dealt with?

Comment: Thanks I will check it out, will axios POST work with Django session auth ?

Comment: I think it is possible but most of the time you would use jwt or token auth

Comment: I can use token authentication, but it is less secure as we store it in localStorage

Comment: Why are you using POST, are you trying to post something to the server? I never used Axios but I think it doesn't send cookies with requests by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically

Comment: To a certain degree it depends on your setup. If Django is serving up the react files on the same server then using SessionAuthentication in django_rest will work fine

Comment: You need to pass the CSRF_TOKEN https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, it is the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) you can obtain the `csrftoken` with the following script:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Or, by using [Javascript Cookie Library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/):

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
```

Then, all you have to do is to update your `axios` call to send it as a header:

```
const likebutton = (id) => {
    axios.post(`/api/post/${id}/like/`, { headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken } })
}
```