# cookie not set in the axios request header

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios, cross-domain, setcookie

1. I am having sprin boot application as my back end and vue js in the
   front end
2. Both are running in my localhost but with different ports
3. I am using axios to make api calls to my back end server
4. My login api works perfetcly and resturns the response with set
   cookie header

But cookie value  not being set in the request header and all other api fails with authentication problem because cookie value (session id) not present in the header
sample response header with set-cookie on authentication

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=C6A3DE7E13C60F33D777875DB610EED2; Path=/a; HttpOnly
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked
date: Tue, 12 May 2020 15:20:17 GMT
connection: close
```

Below is my proxy configuration in vue.config.js

```
 devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080/abc",
        secure: false,
        onProxyReq: function(request) {
          request.setHeader("origin", "http://localhost:8080/abc");
        }
      }
    },
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
```

This is my axios instance creation with "withCredentials:true"

```
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: "/",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});
```

Below is my web secuirty configuration in the server side

```
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/reset-password").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

**Note**:This works in the postman because post man automatically adds the cookie in the request header

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known issue with axios. Try setting the default value like this

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/587#issuecomment-275890961

Comment: tried adding above property before creating axios instance still i am facing the same issue

Comment: what errors are you getting in your console? Also this thread might be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically