# Cookie sent from node server on localhost to ejs client but not sent back on subsequent requests from axios in browser. Working in Postman

Tags: express, cookies, axios, cors, ejs

#### Problem

I have two express node apps - one acting purely as a REST server and the other is the front end using ejs and sending requests to the back-end using axios. I'm trying to get this working in my dev environment where both apps are running on localhost.

I'm trying to log in at `http://localhost:3000/login` which sends the username/password as a POST request to `http://localhost:4000/login` and the `Set-Cookie` header is being set correctly for the token:

```
'set-cookie': 'token=[redacted]; Max-Age=28800; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 05 Apr 2023 20:42:47 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict',
```

But then when redirected to the `http://localhost:3000/transactions` page after success, the cookie is not being sent so the auth fails.

#### What I've tried

This code is working for cookies using Postman which led me to think it's an issue with Chrome's security changes and/or CORS issue though I'm not getting any CORS error messages in the chrome console.

[Other stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests) seem to confirm this theory but I still haven't been able to successfully send the cookie with subsequent requests to the server (i.e. on the `/transactions` call below)

My server side CORS config is this now, I think I've covered all the bases in the above question but I still suspect here's where my problem is:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000','http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'x-csrf-token'],
    exposedHeaders: ['*', 'Authorization', "X-Set-Cookie"]
}));
```

- I know I need to send the request with credentials, I've tried it both in each request and as a default [Just in case it's an axios issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754817/cookie-not-set-in-the-axios-request-header).
- I know browsers have special handling of localhost where it's treated as a secure environment in some scenarios but I'm not clear if this is the case for setting secure cookies - I've switched the values of `secure: true/false` and `sameSite: "Strict","None"` to all their combinations but no change.
- I tried switching everything (server and client) over to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` anyway but there was no change.
- I tried installing a local SSL certificate using `mkcert` to make sure I could set `secure: true` and `sameSite: "None"` properly but no change. Note I removed this code before posting below as it seems like other people have got this working without needing HTTPS on localhost so I abandoned this and haven't included it in the below code.

Any ideas on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

##### Extended code

###### Server - http://localhost:4000/ index.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

let app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000','http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'x-csrf-token'],
    exposedHeaders: ['*', 'Authorization', "X-Set-Cookie"]
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(require('./routes/general/authentication.js'));
app.use(require('./handlers/authHandler.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/general/generalRoute.js'));

// Start the server
if(!module.parent){
    let port = process.env.PORT != null ? process.env.PORT : 4000;
    var server = app.listen(port, 'localhost', function() {
        console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

###### authentication.js

process.env.SECURE_COOKIE = false

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const db = require('../../database/database');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});

const secret = process.env['SECRET'];
const dbURL = process.env['DB_URL'];
const saltRounds = 10;

router.post('/login', [ 
  check('username').exists().escape().isEmail(),
  check('password').exists().escape()
  ], async(req, res, next) => {
    try {

        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.statusCode = 400;
            return next('Authentication failed! Please check the request');
        }

        res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

        if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
            let dbhash = await db.getHashedPassword(req.body.username);
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, dbhash, async function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.error = err;
                    return next('Authentication failed! Please check the request');
                }
                if (result) {
                    let userData = await db.getUserAuthData(req.body.username);
                    if (userData.app_access) {
                        let token = jwt.sign(
                            { user_id: userData.id },
                            secret,
                            { expiresIn: '24h' }
                        );
                        res.cookie("token", JSON.stringify(token), {
                            secure: process.env.SECURE_COOKIE === "true",
                            httpOnly: true,
                            withCredentials: true,
                            maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 8 hours
                            sameSite: "Strict",
                            domain: "localhost"
                        });
                        res.statusCode = 200;
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            response: 'Authentication successful!'
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.statusCode = 401;
                        return next('User is not authorised');
                    }
                } else {
                    res.statusCode = 401;
                    return next('Incorrect username or password');
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 400;
            return next('Authentication failed! Please check the request');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});
  
module.exports = router;
```

###### authHandler.js

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
const secret = process.env['SECRET'];

var checkToken = function(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.cookies.token;
    console.log(req.headers);
    if (token) {
        // Remove Bearer from string
        if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
            token = token.slice(7, token.length);
        } 
        // Remove quotes around token
        else if (token.startsWith('"')) {
            token = token.substring(1, token.length-1);
        }
        jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 401;
                return next('Authentication failed! Credentials are invalid');
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        return next('Authentication failed! Please check the request');
    }
};

module.exports = checkToken;
```

###### Client - http://localhost:3000/

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:4000";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('resources'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get('/transactions', async (req, res) => {
      axios.get('/budget/transactions', {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.request);
            res.render('transactions', { name : 'transactions', title : 'transactions', ...response.data});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.render('transactions', { name : 'transactions', title : 'transactions', ...status });
        });
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    axios.post('/login', 
    {
      username: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    },
    {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers);
    if (response.data.success === true) {
      res.redirect('/transactions');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. I was barking up the wrong tree with CORS - all the other answers I found turned it into a bit of a red herring.

My problem was [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72981636/pass-cookie-with-axios-request) that even though my "client" app was accessed through a browser, because I was using ejs it essentially meant that it's two servers talking to each other:

`Browser -> EJS server -> REST endpoint server.`

This meant that the browser had no knowledge of the cookies that were being sent back by the set-cookie header, and cookies are only saved by default when the client receiving the set-cookie header is a browser - axios does not save them by default when running inside an express server so I had to add manual handling of saving and sending the cookie on to the browser. See full client code below.

###### Client - http://localhost:3000/

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const config = require('./config.json');
const axios = require('axios');
const cookieParser = require('cookie');
const params404 = { name : '404', title : "404 Not Found" };
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:4000";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('resources'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get('/transactions', async (req, res) => {
    let cookie = req.headers.cookie;
    let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    if (cookie) {
        headers.Cookie = cookie;
    }
    axios.get('/budget/transactions', {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => {
        res.render('transactions', { name : 'transactions', title : 'transactions', ...response.data});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err?.response?.data != null) {
            console.error(err.response.data);
        } else {
            console.error(err);
        }
        let status = { success: err.status!=null?err.status:false }
        res.render('transactions', { name : 'transactions', title : 'transactions', ...status });
    });
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    axios.post('/login', 
        {
        username: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
        },
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
    if (
        response.data.success === true && 
        response?.headers["set-cookie"] != null && 
        response.headers["set-cookie"][0] != null
    ) {
        let token = cookieParser.parse(response?.headers["set-cookie"][0]).token;
            res.cookie("token", token, {
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                withCredentials: true,
                maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 8 hours
                sameSite: "None"
            });
        res.redirect('/transactions');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000");
});
```

I kept the CORS settings in place despite it not being relevant to the actual answer here's the final config I settled on that works with the above on localhost (for completeness):

###### authentication.js

```
res.cookie("token", JSON.stringify(token), {
                            secure: true,
                            httpOnly: true,
                            withCredentials: true,
                            maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 8 hours
                            sameSite: "None",
                            path: "/",
                        });
```