# fetching header with cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-cookies, csrf-token

I am using fetch in my react website. So, the server is sending me a set-cookie as

```
set-cookie: sessionid=8pw2k1il82a7ecsqomouww1j9dt3i20f; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
```

So, now i want send it as cookie in my request headers.
I am new to this so having trouble on how to generate csrf token. here is the function where i want cookie request header.

```
  return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL}/api-auth/check-session/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    credentials: "include",
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically, it does make use of [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) tho

Comment: Yeah using axios instead of fetch fixed my problem, thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out!