# Preserve cookies between requests using AXIOS (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, cookies, axios

```
$ node -v v10.15.0
"axios": "^0.19.2",
```

I am trying to keep cookies from response header field 'set-cookie' - just like browsers do.
I used to use this module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and there was an option `request.defaults({jar: true})` which worked well.

For axios I reqd that `{withCredentials: true}` would do the job - but it DOESN'T.

Here is an example code:

```js
axios({ url: 'https://google.com/', method: 'get', withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('res.headers = ', res.headers);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR >>>> ', err);
  });

axios({ url: 'https://google.com/', method: 'get', withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    // console.log("res.headers = ", res.headers);
    console.log('REQUEST HEADERS: ', res.request._header);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR >>>> ', err);
  });
```

The console result is the following:

```js
res.headers = {
  date: 'Tue, 08 Sep 2020 09:42:24 GMT',
  expires: '-1',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
  p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."',
  server: 'gws',
  'x-xss-protection': '0',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'set-cookie': [
    '1P_JAR=2020-09-08-09; expires=Thu, 08-Oct-2020 09:42:24 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure',
    'NID=204=hqIOtyoskrispJi7WvceHmix8PF_tVmV6FArMX_LwcvaFRNYzTj85TZp-MXsmOXL0STJBUX0LjsUXpuPF__yx7urLiXyxFKiFsi8RpPheqyrP4XNTwrHXqXPQVqxY0KEpO_XS9ITMVrMGJ5GBSfQB4Ii63o6x4icknqZ-1k4FA8; expires=Wed, 10-Mar-2021 09:42:24 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly',
  ],
  'alt-svc':
    'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
};

REQUEST HEADERS: GET / HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* User-Agent: axios/0.19.2 Host: www.google.com Connection: close
```

As you can see the first response provides many cookies to be set, but the consecutive request doesn't send them.

How to make the axios keep the cookies between requests?

Comment: Can you try it with moving the second axios request to the `.then` part of the first one? I wonder if the second is getting executed before first one's response is received...

Comment: Ping @Hairi - have you tried it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically might suit your purpose. or the axios with cookie jar npm package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well... I'm too lazy to do things the hard way, so I'd just do something like this, using [axios-cookie-jar-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support):

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;
const tough = require('tough-cookie');
 
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);
 
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();
 
axios
  .get('https://google.com', {
    jar: cookieJar, // tough.CookieJar or boolean
    withCredentials: true, // If true, send cookie stored in jar
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(cookieJar);
  });
```