# Chrome not allowing Set-Cookie even from the same (sub)domain

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, csrf, laravel-sanctum

Here is my configuration:

**SERVER**

Laravel 8 application that uses Sanctum to provide access to REST API. It is configured to run on `http://b8/`

**CLIENT**

A separate Vue CLI 3.0 SPA that connects to the API using session-based cookie authentication method. I have configured Vue CLI Serve to run it at `http://app.b8/`.

**PROBLEM**

Chrome does not allow Set-Cookie operation even when both server and client are on the same domain. After going through several posts and articles, I have successfully run it in Postman, but the real Vue application that runs in the browser can't set Sanctum cookie and thus cannot login.

Here is my configuration:

**.env**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.b8
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,b8,app.b8,app.b8:8080
```

**vue.config.js**

```
...
devServer: {
    proxy: "http://b8/api/v1", 
    host: "app.b8"
},
```

**Login function in Vue application**

```
async login(context, credentials) {
    axios.get('http://b8/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        axios.post('http://b8/login', credentials).then(response2 => {
          //successfully logged in.
        });
    });            
},
```

**Error msg**

The outer call for `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` route returns successfully and brings Sanctum cookie. However, Chrome thinks that the cookie is invalid for the current domain and therefore doesn't set it. Here is the Dev Tools pane's Cookies tab after the Sanctum token call returns (tooltip showing Chrome's complaint):

[image]

Since the cookie is not set, the following `login` call fails with a `419` error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working. For any future reader, here are the things:

1. The first mistake that I was doing was to use a single word host name. It looks like Chrome (or Sanctum, not sure) wants you to have at least one period in the host name. So I changed it from `b8` to `b8.cod`.
2. You should keep `same_site` attribute set to `lax`. `none` is a rather dangerous value. Chrome now shows `none` as a potential issue.
3. `SESSION_DOMAIN` should be set to `.b8.cod` with a leading period to support front-end subdomain, as correctly suggested by the documentation.
4. All other things should be done as suggested in the question. `axios` must use `withCredentials` set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently set up the exact same thing (Laravel 8 backend with Sanctum + separate Vue Frontend) and it's working.

Your server side setup looks good. Please double-check that the frontend's IP is actually included in your `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` - that caused the `419` error for me sometimes.

On the Vue side, make sure to that you enable the [withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically) in your `axios` instance, e.g.

```
const baseDomain = "http://localhost"
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api`

export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

If the provided suggestion does not help, I can further extend my answer by showing you more of my working backend code.

Comment: Thanks. I have made some progress. Had to set `same_site` configuration to `none` instead of `lax`. Chrome now accepts `XSRF-Token` cookie and does not block it. However I'm now stuck on the next step where `axios` does not seem to be sending this cookie in `X-XSRF-Token` header automatically, even though `withCredentials` configuration is set to `true`. This is currently causing `419` which is expected since Sanctum requires `X-XSRF-Token` header in the request.

Comment: Using `same_site` `none` might be the wrong way since it is working with `lax` for me.  Did you set `'supports_credentials' => true` in the `config/cors.php`?

Comment: Yes I did, but Chrome continued to block my cookies till I set it to `none`. Also strange is the fact that `SESSION_DOMAIN=.b8` doesn't work for me, but `SESSION_DOMAIN=b8` (without leading period) does, which is not what the documentation suggests.

Comment: I finally solved it. Will post my answer shortly. Big thanks for your input.

Comment: @dotNET, please post your answer for this to save a soul.. thanks in advance

Comment: @Folorunso: I had posted it then. Still available above.