# How to manage and send httpOnly stored jwt cookies within React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios, cookie-httponly

I'm actively trying to gain knowledge on `httpOnly` cookie and found out lots of article on it that why should we use it.

But I haven't seen any practical example of how to work with it. From few trial and error, I came to knew that we can't set `httpOnly` flag in browser and needed to be done on server. So I, used `cookie-parser` library accordingly:

```
const express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post('/generateToken', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('AccessToken', JWT_AUTH_TOKEN, {
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 1000),
        sameSite: 'strict',
        httpOnly: true,
        
    })
    res.cookie('RefreshToken', JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN, {
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 31557600000),
        sameSite: 'strict',
        httpOnly: true,
    }).send("hello")
    
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5050);
```

By this I successfully get the cookie stored in my browser with all the property like `sameSite`, `HttpOnly` except `secure:true` as I'm on local host. But the problem is as we cant access these `httpOnly` token with javascript, How do I send it to particular routes with proper header like below

```
let token = req.headers['authorization'];
```

and send httpOnly cookie `refreshToken` to lets say `/refresh` Route to get new `accessTokens` with Axios or whats the way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have set the cookies with HttpOnly flag, the cookies will be automatically sent via HTTP request from the browser to the server. You don't have to explicitly set it in HTTP Header.

With `cors` installed at the server, you can access the cookie with `req.cookies`.

I am not sure with axios, but if using fetch API, we will need to add `credential:'include'` option in the fetch API, so that the HttpOnly cookies can be set.

Take a look at this [post](https://medium.com/@itsgosho2/how-to-transfer-http-only-cookies-with-express-back-end-and-the-fetch-api-2035f0ac48d9).

Answer (score 0):

The property withCredentials can help you, its work with axios and send the cookie

```js
const instance = axios.create({
   withCredentials: true,
   baseURL: BASE_URL
})
instance.get('/todos')
```

see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)
and this topic [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)