# Access token in cookies but validation can't detect it in react.js(axios), works in postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, jwt

so I made a login function which generates an access token in cookies. But when I do validation for the a page the page doesn't detect the cookie, in postman it works but in react it doesn't.

Here is my code, sorry if my explanation is kind of confusing.

jwt.js file

```
const { sign, verify } = require('jsonwebtoken');

const createTokens = (user) => {
    const accessToken = sign(
        { username: user.username, id: user.user_id }, 
        'secret'
    );
    return accessToken;
};

const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies['access-token']

    if (!accessToken) 
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'User not authenticated!'})

    try {
         const validToken = verify(accessToken, 'secret')
         req.user = validToken;
         if(validToken) {
            req.authenticated = true
            return next();
         }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(req.cookies);
        return res.status(400).json({error: err})
    }
};

module.exports = { createTokens, validateToken };
```

routes for users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { Users } = require('../models');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const { createTokens, validateToken } = require('../controllers/jwt');

router.get('/', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const userList = await Users.findAll()
    res.json(userList);
});

router.get('/:id', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const user = await Users.findByPk(id);
    res.json(user);
});

router.post('/', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { username, 
            email, 
            password, 
            first_name,
            last_name } = req.body;
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
        Users.create({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: hash,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name
        });
        res.json('User successfully added')
    });
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await Users.findOne({ where: {username: username}});

    if(!user) res.status(400).json({error: `Username does not exist!`});

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
        if(!match) res.status(400).json({error: 'Wrong password!'})

        const accessToken = createTokens(user);

        res.cookie('access-token', accessToken, {
            maxAge: 60*60*24*30*1000, //30 days
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
            httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/'
        });

        user.password = undefined;

        res.json(accessToken);
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is how I call it without the validateToken, what am I missing? lol. Really confused right now.

```
    const [ usersList, setUsersList ] = useState ([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/users').then((res) => {
        setUsersList(res.data)
      })
    }, []);
```

Comment: are you already logged in when you fetch all users?

Comment: After logging in I can fetch all users with postman, otherwise if I dont login first it'll give "user not authenticated". My problem is that I'm confused on how to get the access token from the cookie and let the page know I am authenticated to view it.(sorry if it is confusing)

Comment: I mean on reactjs

Comment: yes I logged in already, I can see that the cookie has my access token after logging in even when I navigate to another page the cookie with the token is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are sending credentials when calling the endpoint with axios. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178070/1712294 to check how to do it.

Comment: @madmeatballs, if that helped you you can accept the answer so that others are aware the issue has been solved.