# Django login state isn't saving

Tags: python, reactjs, django, authentication

I'm using Django and React to create a login page. When the user clicks on the submit button, I send an `Axios` `POST` request to my Django server to `authenticate` and `login`. In the login function, printing `request.user` works as intended. But as soon as the scope of the function is left, printing `request.user` prints `AnonymousUser`. I've talked to some people about it and they seem to think it's because cookies aren't persisting, but we haven't been able to solve the problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```js
// REACT FORM 
function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const state = login ? "login" : "signup";

    axios
        .post(`http://localhost:8000/auth/${state}`, {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            setRedirectMessage(response.data);
            axios
                .post("http://localhost:8000/auth/user")
        })
        .catch((err) => alert(err.response.data));
}
```

```py
# LOGIN REQUEST (/auth/login)
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def auth_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("You are already logged in")
    username, password = get_credentials(request)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Those credentials do not exist")
    login(request, user)
    print(user) # PRINTS CORRECTLY
    print(request.user) # PRINTS CORRECTLY
    return HttpResponse("You have successfully logged in with username " + username)
```

```py
# GET REQUEST TO CHECK LOGIN STATE (auth/user)
@csrf_exempt
def get_user(request):
    print(request.user)
    return HttpResponse("Hey there")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for the link. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ok I've done some looking into it. After setting `withCredentials: true`, I get the following error: `Credentials flag is true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not "true".`, so I attempted whitelisting my front end in `settings.py` like so: `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000']` but the error still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is needed in settings.py:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/