# How can send deviceId or userId in header axios in next js SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use NextJs and make several pages with SSR(server-side rendering)
I have to send the userId to the server

At first, I realized I had to use a cookie

```
npm i js-cookie
```

but I use **Redux-Saga** and I call API in Redux Action
For sending Cookie into Redux Action from the SSR page I use this code

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async ({ store, query, req }) => {
let cookie = req.headers.cookie;
store.dispatch(loadProductDetailData(`${id}`,cookie));
})
```

for export deviceId from the cookie, I make this function

```
export const getCookie = (cookie: string, key: string) => {
let value = ''
cookie.split(';').forEach((e) => {
    if (e.includes(key)) {
        value = e.split('=')[1]
    }
})
return value
```

}

I call this function

```
getCookie(cookie,'deviceId')
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically ?

Comment: this is for serverside rendering

Comment: Are your `deviceId` and `userId` stored in cookies? How are you handling the `cookie` value passed to `loadProductDetailData` and where's the `axios` request?

Comment: yes, I stored it in the cookie. I add code for export deviceId