# Cookies not being sent with Axios

Tags: django, vue.js, cookies, axios, nuxt.js

I have a form built on Nuxt/vuejs. On the backend side on django the CSRF protection is enabled which now expects two things in the Api call **X-CSRFToken** as a header and **csrftoken** as a Cookie , I tested the Api by calling the Api through Postman which works fine but in case Of Vue it is not sending the Cookies with post request let me show you my code

**Axios post request**

```
const headers = {
    "X-CSRFToken": "some token",
    "Cookie": "csrftoken=some token",
}
await axios.post(`onboarding/first-name-last-name-email/`, {
    "first_name": "uneeb2",
    "last_name": "sad",
    "email": "asdsa@asd.colm"
}, {
    headers: headers
}, {
    withCredentials: true
})
```

I have also tried **Fetch** is it also having the same issue

```
fetch(
  'https://staging.goqube.io/api/onboarding/first-name-last-name-email/',
  { credentials: 'include' ,method: "POST",headers:headers} // could also try ''
).then(res => {
  if (res.ok) return res.json()
  // not hit since no 401
})
```

I also tried setting default values in axios it worked for header key but the cookie is still not sent

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
```

one important thing to mention here CORS is enabled by server, so I am not doing anything specific for that.

I also tried setting the cookie as natively by

```
document.cookie = "csrftoken=some token; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 16 Feb 2023 08:02:50 GMT;";
```

through this I can see the Cookie being set on browser but this still not sends the cookie with post request

As you can see I've also tried **withCredentials: true** which was one of the common proposed solutions by in my case this did not work as well.

About the Server config , the Django server is a standalone remote server and the same goes for Nuxt App as well.

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, can anyone point out to me what can be the issue?

Comment: Did you find a way out? I am having the same problem with react 
here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455340/axios-not-sending-csrf-token-to-django-backend-even-after-trying-all-suggested-c

Comment: no luck, had to de-proritize the issue at that point

Comment: @unneebmeer I am still stuck with same issue

Answer (score 5):

**I had the same problem this is how I solved it**

In order for axios to send the cookies `withCredentials` should be `true`, and while `withCredentials` is `true` the backend must send an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header, else you'll get a [cors missing allow credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMIssingAllowCredentials) error and the cookies will not be set in the browser (*the problem now is axios can't send the cookies since they were not even set in the browser to begin with*).

You said you have `CORS` enabled so I assume you have `corsheaders` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and you have added your vue front end url to the `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` list in `settings.py`. You should also add `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` to `settings.py`.

Now in your vue app set the csrf cookie and header names like below this way you won't need to manually get the cookie value and set it to the `X-CSRFToken` header, axios will do that.

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken"
```

then set `withCredentials` to `true` while making the request or you can set it as default like below

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

You can refer to [this](https://yoongkang.com/blog/cookie-based-authentication-spa-django/) blog post

Answer (score 2):

Copy pasting my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically/77520331#77520331):

**Update (Nov, 2023):**

According to the latest changes, there is a new property: **`withXSRFToken`**.
You need to explicitly set it `true` to send the XSRF token.

From the [pull request](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/6046#issue-1968991555):

> So now the user must explicitly set withXSRFToken to true to send XSRF token to third-party origins.
> By default withXSRFToken is undefined - the token will be sent only to the same origin.