# Set a cookie in Nest JS using POST request (ViteJs + REACT JS)

Tags: node.js, cookies, nestjs

I am using nest js and want to set the cookies when the user will hit a specific endpoint:

```
@Get()
setCookiesApi(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response:Response) {
  response.setCookie('key', 'value')
}
```

This code works and the cookies are set in `cookies` storage from the `Application` tab in Chrome. If i try setting cookies using post:

```
@Post()
setCookiesApi(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response:Response) {
  response.setCookie('key', 'value')
}
```

My code on UI:

```
  try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/hello`,
        user,
        {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            withCredentials: true,
          },
          data: user,
        },
      );
      if (response.data) {
        // sss
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof AxiosError) {
        if (err.response) {
          toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        }
      }
    }
```

main.js file

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors({ origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173', credentials: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

...then the `cookies` storage is empty and no cookie is set. 
 Question: Why `get` request works but `post` not and how to solve this?

Comment: How do you make the request?

Comment: @Konrad, i added a short code in my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)

Comment: @Konrad, do you know what could be the issue because i tried everything

Comment: Are you sure that you are hitting the correct endpoint?

Comment: @Konrad yes, 100%

Comment: @Konrad, i am using Vite with react js, noticed that when in run my code using CRA where i have localhost, then all cookies are set, but when using vite with `http://127.0.0.1:5173/` url, the cookies are not set. Do the cookies work only with localhost?

Comment: Should work either way

Comment: @Konrad, i changed the Vite url to `http://localhost:5173/` and it is working but not with `http://127.0.0.1:5173/`

Comment: This is unexpected, I didn't know that. You can ask another question like "Why cookies work for `localhost` but not for `127.0.0.1`?", you will probably gather more attention and get the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the GET request works because it is an HTTP method that allows for retrieving data from a server, and the `setCookie()` method is used to set a cookie in the response.

The POST request doesn't work because POST is typically used for creating or modifying data on a server, and the `setCookie()` method is not designed to handle data modifications.

Comment: so there is no way to set cookies using post request?

Comment: @Asking should work with `post` request as well

Comment: @Konrad, i tested on my side and it does not work.

Comment: @Konrad, doe it matter if i am on http not https? I am on my local env, using Vite for react js and nest js.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `POST` method as well. Try something similar like this:

```js
@Post()
setCookiesApi(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response:Response) {
  response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie);

  return response.send();
}
```

Comment: i checked `Aplication/Storage/Cookies` and there is nothing. It does not appear.

Comment: @Asking have you used the `app.use(cookieParser())` middleware in main.ts?

Comment: ,yes, also i updated my question with some details. Couls you help please?

Comment: i also noticed that the cookie is stored in request's `Cookies` tab in Chrome, but it is not stored in the Application/Storage/Cookies