# Axios won´t redirect and give me correct Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, axios

I have a POST Request which works perfect in Insomnia and the chain is the following:

1. I Post some Data with the Info that i am a User and want to access a Site without password
2. It gets accepted and with a Set-Cookie i am getting a session key so i can move on
3. With that sessKey i can access a get request and get the data

Here is the Insomnia Request and the Timeline for the Redirect and Request:

[image: 1]

As I said it works perfectly with Insomia, but I tried it with Axios, here is some Info and Code:

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://SomeSite/',
  data: 'action=set&name=User&pwd=' //Saying i want to identify as user without pwd
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data); //Not giving me the correct data
})
```

I found a workaround by providing a Sessionkey, which i get from the Request, then it will redirect me directly and axios gives me the correct HTML, but i have to change the Session Key daily. It would be better if axios would automaticly get and set the Cookie with the Request like Insomnia does.

Comment: On first glance, are you sure about axios.request? Why not use axios.post(options). You don't have to specify request method in options object then. Also weird to see data in plain text, usually it's an object.

Comment: Is this supposed to be server- or client-side JavaScript? And if client-side, is this a cross-domain request? If so, you will need to specify that you want cookies to be accepted, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178070/1427878

Comment: "Not giving me the correct data" — What do you get? What would be correct? What is the difference? Please read [ask].

Comment: I also tried using Axios.Post also didnt work. It is Server Side JS. To explain the problem better here is what i want: I have a UTN manager Website where i want to read Information about USB Dongle Devices I have connected, which I should be able to do with the html of the website. The Website has a Form, before i can access the Information, therefore I put the plain data in the Post Method, so i get redirected directly to the Info Site and with insomnia i get the correct HTML of the Info site, but with Axios i get the html of the Form Site.