# How can I set session cookie with localhost

Tags: session, axios, session-cookies

I've my application(react app) running in localhost:3000 & my express server running on https://some-domain.com, I'm unable to set cookie from my express to localhost.
I'm using express-session & redis-store.

Comment: Maybe this could help:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231372/8962088](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231372/8962088) It seems to be a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

To set "credentials" in server we need this line:

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)` add this in cors middleware

This would let you handle credentials included in headers.

You also have to tell to axios to set credentials in headers with:

`withCredentials: true`

Comment: Yup, but still its not working.., If I run both app in localhost it works but, on the different domain not working..!