# Fetch my backend express from the backend of my frontend nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I have a issue:

1. I use express for my backend port:3001

2)I use next Js for my frontend part( but nextjs have also frontend and backend)

When i fetch a road from the frontend nextjs to the backend express it work perfectly

but when i try to fetch on the backend nextjs to my backend express impossible to do it

the code

nextjs => dashboard/page.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function dashboard() {
  async function test() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/next/status', {withCredentials: true});
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Une erreur est survenue :", error);
    }
  }

  test();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

That fetch return this

```
Une erreur est survenue : AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401
    at settle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:21:16)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:496:81)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: 'http',
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.5.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 224967,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _header: 'GET /api/next/status HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.5.0\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:3001\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/api/next/status',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 401,
      statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 20,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '26',
      etag: 'W/"1a-pljHtlo127JYJR4E/RYOPb6ucbw"',
      date: 'Thu, 07 Sep 2023 11:56:42 GMT',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: 'http',
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object [AxiosHeaders]],
      withCredentials: true,
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/next/status HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.5.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3001\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/api/next/status',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { message: 'Unauthorized' }
  }
```

par contre si je faismon fetch cote client comme ceci

```
Une erreur est survenue : AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401
    at settle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:21:16)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:496:81)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: 'http',
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.5.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 224967,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _header: 'GET /api/next/status HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.5.0\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:3001\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/api/next/status',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 401,
      statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 20,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '26',
      etag: 'W/"1a-pljHtlo127JYJR4E/RYOPb6ucbw"',
      date: 'Thu, 07 Sep 2023 11:56:42 GMT',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: 'http',
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object [AxiosHeaders]],
      withCredentials: true,
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/next/status',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/next/status HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.5.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3001\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/api/next/status',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { message: 'Unauthorized' }
  }
```

I can't understand why it do that. My CORS settings on the Express backend are properly configured. Maybe it's not possible to fetch from a backend to another backend. Here's the route called on the Express backend side.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const isAuthenticated = require('../../middleware/authorized');
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const router = express.Router();
const FrontUser = require('../../models/FrontUser');
const DiscordUser = require('../../models/DiscordUser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


router.get('/status',isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.user){
   res.status(200).send(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized'});
  }
});
```

with what protect my road

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const isAuthenticated = router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('reqUser', req.user);
    if (req.user) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        //return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
    }
});

module.exports = isAuthenticated;
```

I thank you by advance for any help you can give me too much time loose on that i have tried with chatgpt and we don' t find the answer.

I wish you a good day

Comment: possibly, something to do with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in express: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically

Comment: req.user in your controller is perhaps undefined. Did you implement JWT? what is the value of req.user from your controller? Is the user is authenticated?

Comment: Can do the both thing because my road work when i am on client side of nextjs it is not working when i am on server side of next and when i reach a backend road of express.
i think it is cookie issue because i can not catch the client next cookie on server side so i need to pass it on like Nafi Asib advise me
But thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an `401` response. I assume you have cookies set in your browser. And you are setting `{withCredentials: true}` to your axios request in Next.js backend. If that's the case then showing `401` from express is normal.

Reason is Next.js backend don't have access to the cookies of your browser. Remember, it's running on a server. So you need to manually pass the cookie in that request. You can use `next/headers` in your code to get the cookies and then attach to the request

Comment: Ty for your quick answer, and i think it is the good way to do it.

I try now and comeback to you if i have another issue on that problem

Answer (score 1):

So two things to do it if you are in the middleware.tsx file the documentation nextjs 13 are wrong you need to do it like this for have the cookie

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';


export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
 

  const cookie = req.cookies.get('your cookie name')?.valueOf();

console.log('cookie', cookie)
}
```

and if you are on a page or components and you want import server side some fetch with cookie to clientside

```
'use server'
 
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function getStatus() {
  const getCookie = async (name: string) => {
    return cookies().get(name)?.value ?? '';
  }

  const cookie = await getCookie('connect.sid');

  console.log('cookies',cookie)

  const res = await fetch(`your url`, {headers: {Cookie: `yourcookiename=${cookie}`}, cache: 'no-store'  })
  const datas = await res.json()
  console.log('users1', datas);
  return datas
}
```

it will work perfectly

ty all for your answer and help