# Why I am not able to see jwt Cookie I sent from server after authentication?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, cookies

I am working on a mern app where I sent jwt token in response using cookie. But when i login successfully jwt doesnt show in Application/Cookies/http:localhost:300. (i am using vite) I will put some images down below. On the server (backend) i successfully set cookie, set expirations option, httpOnly option etc, and auth middleware also works fine on server. Though i see cookie in response of login request, i dont see it in cookies tab. When testing in postman, cookies is successfuly set there and middleware works, but i dont see jwt in chrome

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnnIo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60bJU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtRbE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGMU4.png)
```

I tried deleting cookies, restarting servers, restarting computer. Coudlnt find anything on the internet or resources are very old

Comment: Please follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and I solved it by inserting `{withCredentials: true}` as options in the Axios request.

```js
export async function yourApiCall(): {
    const URL = "your_url"
    const response = await axios.get(URL, {
        withCredentials: true,
    })
    return response
}
```

A more detailed explanation is given here: [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)

Comment: Thank you for commenting my post, but im using redux and apiSlice to send requests. Not axios, any other solution?