# HttpOnly cookie is not saved in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, spring, cookies

I have a problem regarding a Spring/React application. I managed to generate JWT tokens that are sent by the backend through cookies. Chrome sees the cookies in the header but does not save them and I can't figure out why:

Here is the Java Spring Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
public class AuthController {

  private final AuthService authService;
  private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestBody AuthRequestDTO authRequestDTO, HttpServletResponse response) {
    AuthResponseDTO authResponseDTO = authService.loginUser(authRequestDTO);
    ResponseCookie resCookie = ResponseCookie.from("jwtToken", authResponseDTO.getToken())
      .httpOnly(true)
      .sameSite("None")
      .path("/")
      .maxAge(3600)
      .build();
    response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", resCookie.toString());
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Login successful");
  }
```

Here is the request I make for logging in the user:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
        email: username,
        password: password
      }, {
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include'
      });
      const { token } = response.data;
      console.log(token);
      setToken(token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
    }
  };
```

Below are the headers I receive (but the Cookies tab is empty)

[image]

Comment: This may be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically