# Unable to send JWT token through cookie in GET api

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, axios, jwt

I have a user login where I send a JWT token as a cookie. Then, when API is called from the client side, it passes a cookie to the backend in the request header. This works as expected in a `POST` request, but while calling `GET` API, this cookie value does not pass in the request's headers.

express.js(Cors configurations)

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header(`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `GET,PUT,POST,DELETE`);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});
```

user.js

```
user.token = user.generateAuthToken({userType: user.userType, email: user.email})
await user.save();
res.cookie('x-auth-token', user.token, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true,})
return res.json({ success: true, token: requestData.token })
```

For calling API from my client, which is in React, I use Axios. I have called `GET` APIs before, and after calling `POST` APIs, token is passed in all `POST` APIs, but does not work in GET APIs.

services.js

```
//Works as expected
    export const callPostAPI = async (api, parameters, headers = {}) => { 
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + api, parameters, {headers}, { withCredentials: true });
            return (response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
   
// Doesn't work as expected(Does not send JWT token from cookie) 
    export const callGetAPI = async (api, header = {}) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + api, { withCredentials: true });
            return response.data
        }   
        catch(error) {
            throw error
        }    
    }
```

Comment: for the post request you are not passing the `withCredentials: true` correctly to request config object. so post also should not be working unless you are not making cross domain request. anyway have you tried this solution for GET, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77520331/4168998 ?

Comment: @v1shva Thanks for comment. I'm passing ```withCredentials: true``` to both APIs. Please go through the question once again in the service.js section.

Comment: what I said was you are not passing correctly. `axios.post` only accept 3 parameters, you are passing 4 here? which version of axios are you using? are you making a cross domain request?

Comment: @v1shva Yes, I'm making a cross-domain request with Axios 1.6.0

Comment: @v1shva I have resolved this issue by removing headers from Axios. Please write down the answer to approve it.